# Use Jquery 2.2 for modern browsers and 1.9 for older browsers as a fallback possible?

Tags: jquery

So recently Jquery released version 2 which stopped supporting older browsers. Minified and with a custom build it is much more faster and smaller (40kb) as opposed to 96 kb version 1.9. The issue is that it doesnt support older browsers so I am forced to use conditional comments to include 1.9 for only ie8 and below. However, as I also need jquery 2.2 for the modern browsers on my page, how do I prevent old ie versions to ignore it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @adeneo Jquery 2.0.2 is much faster. With a custom build it is only 40kb and gzipped im getting near 10kb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the answer on the jQuery website here: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/03/01/jquery-2-0-beta-2-released/

Use the conditional comments as:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="jquery-1.xjs"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
<script src="jquery-2.x.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thanks, I saw that article. So the top conditional comment is only for IE below 9 right? And the script below is readable by all browsers (firefox, safari, ie10 chrome etc) right?

Comment: Yes that's right, the first conditional is entirely into an HTML comment, so it will be ignored by all browsers, except IE<=9, in the second comment, notice how the comment is closed and the script "visible" to any other browser. That is the trick.

Comment: I will accept your answer. What I dont understand what makes the second script visible to all browsers? Is it the <!-->`? This means it is converted into a normal comment, but then it is a normal comment for explorers below 9 as well or not? a little bit confusing.

Comment: The second `<!-->` open and close the comment, but closes also the first `<!--[if gte IE 9]>`. In this way the conditional comment is read by IE9 and below (IE10 doesn't accept anymore conditional comments), and make the script available for modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Put a conditional load around 2.2 as well

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
```